# Scrape number of comments and number of pictures from Aliexpress using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to scrape product data from AliExpress website using selenium, I already scraped the title, price and rating for a whole category but I don't know how can I scrape number of comments and pictures of each product from this "smart lock" category.

This is my code I used to scrape title, proce and rating from the url of smart lock products:

```
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options  
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver  
from pymongo import MongoClient
from time import sleep
from lxml import html 
import pandas as pd
import cssselect
import pymongo
import time


def scrap(subject):
    start_time = time.time()      
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
    url ='https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?trafficChannel=main&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=smart+lock&ltype=wholesale&SortType=total_tranpro_desc'
    
    client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")    
    collection_name = subject
    collection = client["db2"][collection_name] 
    x = collection.delete_many({})   
    for page_nb in range(1, 6):
        
        print('---', page_nb, '---')    
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        driver.get(url.format(page_nb))           
        sleep(2)
        current_offset = 0
        while True:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);")
            sleep(.5)  # JavaScript has time to add elements
            new_offset = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
            if new_offset <= current_offset:
                break
            current_offset = new_offset
        sleep(3)
        tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
        results = []
        for product in tree.xpath('//div[@class="JIIxO"]//a'):
            title = product.xpath('.//h1/text()')
            if title:
                title = title[0]
                price = product.cssselect('div.mGXnE._37W_B span')
                leng = len(price)
                price = [x.text for x in price]

                currency = price[leng-1]

                price = ''.join(price[0:leng-1])

                stars = product.xpath('.//span[@class="eXPaM"]/text()')
                if stars :
                    stars  = stars [0]
                else:
                    stars  = 'None'
               
                row = [title, price, stars]
                results.append(row)
      
        df = pd.DataFrame(results , columns=("Title","Price", "Stars"))
        
        data = df.to_dict(orient = 'records')     
        collection.insert_many(data)
```

for example I want to scrape those two elements :

[image]

Comment: Hi Dina *It is scrape, scraping, scraper - scrap is something completely different.* Anyway, try to scrape links to detail pages and iterate or click them. Would be great if you could improve your question with additional details e.g. What exactly is expected as *number of comments and pictures*? What have you tried so far with focus on the detailpages? Thanks

Comment: I edited my question to show what element I want to scrap. My problem is I don't know how can I access to each product link in the page to get those two elements. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above try to scrape all links on this site:

```
urlList = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[href*="/item/"]')]
```

Than iterate this list and open each detail page:

```
for url in urlList[:2]:
    driver.get(url)
```

Tricky part here, you have to scroll down until you detect an `iframe` that holds the feedback. Extract the `src` and scrape this ressource:

```
...
try:
    iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#feedback iframe').get_attribute('src')
except:
    iframe = None
if new_offset <= current_offset or iframe:
    break
current_offset = new_offset

driver.get(iframe)
print(int(''.join(i for i in driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#transction-feedback > div').text if i.isdigit())))
print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#cb-withPictures-filter +em').text)
```

##### Example

**Note:** *For demo I sliced `urlList[:2]` to get only two iteration, but you could simply delete `[:2]` to get all urls from the list*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?trafficChannel=main&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=smart+lock&ltype=wholesale&SortType=total_tranpro_desc'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get(url)

urlList = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[href*="/item/"]')]

for url in urlList[:2]:
    driver.get(url)
    current_offset = 0
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);")
        sleep(.5)  # JavaScript has time to add elements
        new_offset = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")

        try:
            iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#feedback iframe').get_attribute('src')
        except:
            iframe = None
        if new_offset <= current_offset or iframe:
            break
        current_offset = new_offset

    driver.get(iframe)
    print(int(''.join(i for i in driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#transction-feedback > div').text if i.isdigit())))
    print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#cb-withPictures-filter +em').text)
```